# Zariski-closed sets of the algebraic closure of the rational numbers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

I got the following statements:

[image]

Again, I'm super unsure on how to prove something is wrong. I think 4 is definitely right, but I'm unsure about each of the other statements. We have the Definition, that a Subset of $k^n$ is called Zarisiki-closed if it is the set of solutions to a set of Polynomials.

Comment: Right now this does not meet the standards for a [good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/) on MSE. Luckily, you can fix this with an [edit] which will probably also get you started down the right path: add the definitions you know, add the work you've done and the thoughts you've had so far, etc. (Please also note that [images of text are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/) - the image in your post should be formatted using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).)

Comment: Sorry! I thought in this case that would be fine, because i added the tag algebraic geomety and this question only requires the basic definitions. Anyways i will fix it.

Comment: You're right, this only requires the basic definitions, which makes your idea to omit them worse - they are the most relevant thing to the problem! You will receive more and better targeted help (and you might even figure out your problem in the process of asking it!) if you explain why you're unsure and where you're running in to trouble, so please for the sake of all of us write good-quality questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topology $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ is the cofinite topology. In our case, $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}^1 = \mathbb{A}^1_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}$ so the closed sets are precisely the entire space and finite sets. Therefore, $(4)$ is closed and the others are not closed.

Comment: Oh yeah that is true. Thank you so much!